# adding values of one column and incerting in diffrent table mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 2 tables customer and milk as shown below

**customers**

```
customers (cid, name, price, total);
```

**milk**

```
milk (mid, customer_id, milk_letters, mprice)
```

I'm trying

```
$cid = $_POST['cid'];
```

i want to update customer tables as sum(mprice) of milk where customer_id = cid

Comment: You aren't trying enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sql code :

```
UPDATE customers c
SET total=(SELECT SUM(mprice) FROM milk WHERE customer_id=c.cid)
WHERE c.cid=$cid
```

also use `intval`

```
$cid = intval($_POST['cid']);
```